# Facebook Attribution API - List of attribution channels

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am really having a very hard time to use [Facebook Attribution API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/attribution/). On the documentation it is mentioned that we can break your results down by source_channel but those channels are really general (picture bellow) [image]

Would it be possible to breakdown based on the top sources listed on `https://business.facebook.com/attribution/<BUSINESS_ID>/performance`?

[image]